# How can I set HTTP headers in Glassfish server

Tags: java, browser, http-headers, glassfish, browser-cache

I want to set the "Expires" HTTP response header when my Glassfish server serves static resources like Javascript and image files. (because to force the browser to cache them)

How can I do this in Glassfish V 3.0.1 server?

Comment: Seems like this might need to be on serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

Glassfish uses catalina for servlet container. Extend the DefaultServlet, override something like `doGet()` and add the headers you need.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.html

Mount your own default servlet to `/`:

```
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>mydefault</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is using [**HttpServletResponseWrapper**](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html)

[Another approch is using filter , here is very good article :**Caching static resources in glassfish**](http://blogs.oracle.com/cwebster/entry/caching_static_resources_in_glassfish)

Comment: Filter Servlets not working for me. If I set the header in the filter, it is then overridden automatically somewhere in some stage latter in my JSF application.

Comment: @MISS_DUKE - did you ever find a fix for this? I'm hitting the same problem myself now. Thanks.

Comment: Afraid not - the problem is that when I set the ETag, Last-Modified & Cache-Control headers only the Cache-Control header gets sent in the response. The DefaultServlet seems to overwrite the ETag and Last-Modified headers, which is unfortunate because they're getting set to (or a derivative of) the deployment time. No way can I get, say, jsf.js to cache.

Answer (score 2):

Are you referencing resources from secure page?? Then The answer of Jigar Joshi i.e.

http://blogs.oracle.com/cwebster/entry/caching_static_resources_in_glassfish

will not work...

If you are having secure page then following will help you out.

[Static resources are not cached referenced from glassfish secure page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468099/static-resources-are-not-cached-referenced-from-glassfish-secure-page/5482987#5482987)